# Recommended reading on how to write proper feature files

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

We recently started practicing BDD with cucumber, and after a few months or so - we can clearly tell that our Achilles heel is writing maintainable feature files. For example:

Some teams wrote very technical feature files that included information about the inner implementation. This made the feature file unreadable by most non-technical people. Another example, is that some teams wrote very generic feature files - thinking of having the smallest possible amount of step definition in order to keep it DRY - but with time, they figured it's very hard to have a readable feature file when you limit yourself to a small amount of steps definitions across the project.

The internet has some tips on how to write the feature file properly, but those are limited, and are good for specific examples. Is there any site, or perhaps a good book, that share some best practices? Some practices that's been gathered from years of experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you have struggled to find a definitive text on the subject, is because, as far as I know, there isn't one. Once you get started and understand the gist of BDD, then the hard part is finding out what works for you.  There are some really good books that will help you to do that a lot more successfully - like Specification By Example, but it is not a one size fits all solution.

In terms of how technically to write your scenarios, it depends on the audience for them.  If one of the benefits of using BDD is that all the relevant stakeholders can talk about features prior to development, then writing them at a level which is accessible to everyone is a necessary part of that.  That said there isn't any reason to go too far with it.  If everyone can contribute then why try harder to make it less technical?

In terms of maintainability, abstraction is key.  Using BDD for websites as an example, as that's what I have most experience with, the most important way of achieving that is using page objects or wrappers to achieve a layer of abstraction between your step definitions and the object you are testing.  By doing this you can have many step definitions that are almost the same that use your wrapper slightly differently, but in terms of maintainability, the vast majority of it will be achieved through small changes to your page objects that propagate through the rest of your automation suite.

That's the way I work, after trying several different approaches over the years.  I don't think that having lots of step definitions makes the code less DRY, as so long as they are implementing a wrapper there isn't really much repeated code.

EDIT: An answer to your question in the comments...

Really there is only one way, all of the variations I've seen are to do with tools.  The tools you use, if you choose to use any will be dependant on the system under test.  The only really important idea is to have a wrapper for each page/screen/area of a screen that handles getting, setting and interacting with your test object.  Then your step definitions contain all of the actual logic.  e.g. handling your assertions or what page object methods you want to call to simulate what a user would do.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply @alannichols and sorry for the late reply. This is useful. Especially the tip on keeping the markup language inside a Page Object and therefore not to be intimidated with a very large amount of step defs. I noted there is a lot of ways people implement the Page Object pattern. You seem to have some experience with that, can you tell me which implementation are you using?

Comment: @Okiba - I replied in an edit to my post as the comment field is size limited.

Comment: Thank you @alannichols. I accepted the answer and I will add to that the official Cucumber book have some good do and do not about feature files that should be looked into by anyone who having the same issue.